# Swift - ThreadSanitizer complaining of data race

Tags: swift, async-await, race-condition

I am running ThreadSanitizer on my project and I am getting some very inconsistent results. My setup is as follows:

1. A wrapper around a URLSession which reports back tasks and their status. I get the tasks via:

```
actor MyMonitor {
  func getTasks() async -> [String: URLSessionTask] {
    await mySession.allTasks.reduce(into: [String: URLSessionTask]()) { newMap, element in
        if let taskDescription = element.taskDescription {
                newMap[taskDescription] = element
       }
    }
  }
}
```

For my unit tests, I have a URLProtocol to mock an actual working request. However, it seems when I call the `getTasks` function, I get a data race. (albeit inconsistent)

The TSan tool states the race is in the above snippet:

> Threading Issues: Data race in (2) await resume partial function for
> MyProject.MyMonitor.getTasks() async -> Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String,
> __C.NSURLSessionTask> at 0x7b6000021400

Is this a false positive, because I do not have control ove URLSession's threading? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're only getting the data race during unit testing, I wouldn't worry about it. But report it to Apple, perhaps.

Comment: I'm seeing similar data race issues in various scenarios when using async/await. In some cases, they appear legitimate. But in other cases, I'm not so sure. I have one case currently where the exact same code that works cleanly on iOS, gets ThreadSanitizer warnings on macOS.